# Update angular material Modal UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-material

I have a variable in the controller:

```
$scope.myName = "Jack";
```

I have a `ng-click=open()` on a button to open a modal. On click I want to change the name of that variable and want to show the updated value in the modal UI. Unfortunately it shows the old value.

```
$scope.open = function(){
    $scope.myName = "changed";

    $mdDialog.show({
            templateUrl: '/app/dataModal.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        })
}


//dataModal.html
<md-dialog ng-controller="myCtrl">{{myName}}</md-dialog>
```

Comment: So you want to update the `myName` scope variable using `dialoge` box. right ?

Comment: @nextt1 yes... on clicking the button, i want to change that variable and then open the modal and display that changed varilabe {{myName}}

Answer (score 1):

**1) If you want to change the scope item** value by using the input in the dialog  then, you should use the promise way to handle dialog that has an input. Check example here: http://codepen.io/shershen08/pen/aNWBBd.

```
$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
  $scope. myName = result;
}, function() {
  $scope. myName = result;
});
```

This should be not in your `$scope.open = function(){` function, but outside of it.

**2) If you need only to display the scope value** in the dialog, then your current code is ok, you just need to edit the template to match:

```
//dataModal.html
<md-dialog>{{myName}}</md-dialog>
```

Here is the demo for this case: http://codepen.io/shershen08/pen/pyPNaM?editors=1010

Comment: There is no input in the dialog, on click just change the variable and show it on the modal UI. I have tried $rootScope, the variable is updated, but not the UI on the modal

Comment: I see I'll update my answer. Did you inject $mdDialog into you controller? Did you get any errors when using your code?

Comment: yes... i did that, modal is opening, but not getting the updated scope data

Comment: can you add your template code - from /app/dataModal.html, maybe the problem is there?

Comment: no need to put ng-controller in the dialog template, leave it like this - <md-dialog>{{myName}}</md-dialog>